# django order_by either columns (date whichever is recent)

Tags: django

I want to order my posts by either the most recent comment.created or post.published_date(in case there is no comment yet).

```
posts_all =ForumPost.objects.all().filter(published_date__lte=timezone.now()).prefetch_related('comments')

posts=posts_all.annotate(max_activity=Max('comments__created')).order_by('-max_activity','-published_date')
```

With the above code, it shows all posts with comments first (ordered by most recent comment activity), then follows all posts that do not have any comment (ordered by recently published).

What I really want is order posts by most recent comment OR recently published. Any idea? Thanks.

**EDIT:to make the question more clear** If there are post A with no comment and published 5 min ago, and post B with comments with recent comment created 20 min ago; post A should be above post B.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can make use of the [**`Coalesce`** function [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/database-functions/#coalesce) to provide a value if `Max('comments__created')` returns `NULL` (this happens if there are no values over which to aggregate:

```
from django.db.models.functions import Coalesce

posts = posts_all.annotate(
    max_activity=Coalesce(Max('comments__created'), 'published_date')
).order_by('-max_activity')
```

Comment: Willem, thank you for quick reply. My question might not be clear. Since if there is comment, the comments__created will always be larger than the post.published_date, so, the ```Greatest```function will always return the ```Max('comments__created')```. If there are post A with no comment and published 5 min ago, and post B with comment with recent comment created 20 min ago; post A should be above post B. But I do not know how to get the result. Can you help?

Comment: @ha-neul: then you should use the `Coalesce` operator.